# Supervisors with backoff

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a supervisor with two worker processes: a TCP client which handles connection to a remote server and an FSM which handles the connection protocol.

Handling TCP errors in the child process complicates code significantly. So I'd prefer to "let it crash", but this has a different problem: when the server is unreachable, the maximum number of restarts will be quickly reached and the supervisor will crash along with my entire application, which is quite undesirable for this case.

What I'd like is to have a restart strategy with back-off; failing that, it would be good enough if the supervisor was aware when it is restarted due to a crash (i.e. had it passed as a parameter to the `init` function). I've found [this mailing list thread](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Supervisor-with-better-restart-strategies-td2330438.html), but is there a more official/better tested solution?

Comment: I would say that the strategy in your case seems wrong. I mean if you want to "let it crash" but at the same time restart it immediately then there is no reason to let it crash because you are just using the supervisor as a retry mechanism. This is plain wrong imho. You should let it crash, put code in your startup sequence if you "wait" for resources and NOT retry by crashing. I've seen this before and usually it is a design error rather than a limitation in the supervisor. Food for thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find our [supervisor cushion](https://github.com/couchbase/ns_server/blob/master/deps/ns_babysitter/src/supervisor_cushion.erl) to be a good starting point.  I use it slow down the restart on things that *must* be running, but are failing quickly on startup (such as ports that are encountering a resource problem).

Comment: Link is 404'ing again.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianAntonelli -- the problem with pointing to live code is that people move things.

Comment: @Dustin link to a specific commit; that way the link will be valid as long as the Git history isn't rewritten. https://alxndr.github.io/blog/2016/05/06/linking-to-code-always-use-an-href-which-is-tied-to-a-specific-commit.html

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem many times working with erlang and tried many solutions.  I think the best best I've found is to have an extra process that is started by the supervisor and starts the that might crash.

It starts the child on start-up,  awaits child exits and restarts the child (with a delay) or exits as appropriate.   I think this is simpler than the back-off server (which you link to) as you only need to keep state regarding a single child.

Another solution that I've used is to have to start the child processes as transient and have a separate process that polls and issues restarts to any processes that have crashed.

Answer (score 2):

So first you want to catch an early termination of the child by using a  `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` in your init.

Then you need to decide how long you want to delay a restart by, for example 10 sec., do this in the

```
handle_info({'EXIT', _Pid, Reason}, State) ->
    erlang:send_after(10000, self(), {die, Reason}),  
    {noreply, State};
```

Lastly, let the process die with

```
handle_info({die, Reason}, State) ->
    {stop, Reason, State};
```

Comment: Hello Roman, and welcome to the site.  We like to keep questions and answers very to-the-point here, so I went ahead and cut your answer down a bit.  Feel free to edit it again if you aren't happy with my changes.